# Swift RegexBuilder convert date String to Date

Tags: swift, swift-regexbuilder

I know the usual way of using DateFormatter style with option of `.withFullDate` to convert a date of style `"yyyy-MM-dd"` (ISO 8601 but just date, not time or timezone) into Swift `Date`

```swift
let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
formatter.formatOptions = [.withFullDate]
let date = formatter.date(from: "2023-10-21")
```

But I am wondering if it is possible to achieve this with new Swift's RegexBuilder `Capture` and maybe with `Transform`?
It seems the  `.date(...)` function requires `locale` but I do not care for the locale, I just want a `String` date to convert into `Date`.

Is it possible to do this using built in date formatter in RegexBuilder? i.e. without writing literal Regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can capture the date string as a `Date` directly

```
One(.iso8601.year().month().day().dateSeparator(.dash))
```

Example

```
let input = "2023-10-21 some other stuff"

let regex = Regex {
    Capture {
        One(.iso8601.year().month().day().dateSeparator(.dash))
    }
    OneOrMore(.any)
}

if let match = input.firstMatch(of: regex) {
    print(match.output.1, type(of: match.output.1))
}
```

> 2023-10-21 00:00:00 +0000 Date